# how to scroll the collection view in uitableview in ios9.0?

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

[image]

I am facing problem only in the IOS 9.0 earlier versions i can able to scroll them easy and also i didnt get any problem like this.
this is my uitableview.I am loading many collectionview in this tableview but when i am trying to select the collectiovew cell in that time i cant able to select and also i cant able to scroll them horizontally.When i am trying to select the cell in that time the entice tableview cell is going to select.please help me how to select the collection view cell and also how to call the target method.
Please help me to resolve this problem.
I am waiting for your suggestions.
to calling the collectioncell i am using the protocol methods.
those are also not reflecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I am not sure if I understand your question.
I assume you have in every table view cell a collection view with a horizontal flow layout. If so, every table view cells would show multiple collection view cells that should be scrolled horizontally.
I would check:

1. Is user interaction enabled for your collection view cell? Otherwise
   a tap would handled by the table view cell.
2. Is scrolling enabled in your collection view?
3. Did you set the delegate for the collection view? Otherwise no
   target method would be called.

Comment: i tried this same app in ios8.4 ,there my  app is working fine, i am getting the problem only in the ios9.0.please provide solution